# How to install and import Qiskit_aqua?

Tags: python, qiskit

I want to run SVM algorithm using Qiskit. For this purpose I need to import some packages from ***qiskit_aqua.utils***. I am writing my code on Google Colaboratory. But while trying to import this package it shows me the following error.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit_aqua'

I have tried to import every thing from Qiskit. But no changes have come. Here is my code.

```
!pip install qiskit
from qiskit import * 
from qiskit_aqua.utils import split_dataset_to_data_and_labels
from qiskit_aqua.input import get_input_instance
from qiskit_aqua import run_algorithm
```

I even tried to import ***Aer*** using this command. But still it is of no use.

Help me finding the solution.

```
!pip install qiskit
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit_aqua.utils import split_dataset_to_data_and_labels
from qiskit_aqua.input import get_input_instance
from qiskit_aqua import run_algorithm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqua is a subpackage of Qiskit, so you need to use `.` instead of `_`. Your imports therefore should be

```
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit.aqua.utils import split_dataset_to_data_and_labels
from qiskit.aqua.input import get_input_instance
from qiskit.aqua import run_algorithm
```